# Crystal report not viewing properly

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Image shows the way crystal reports opens for me.
only small portion of report is visible.it works on other computers.

i tried to uninstall report viewer and crystal report, 
installed again..still no change.

**application background:**
using SAP Crystal reports 13.0.4.705,
MS Report viewer 2010 SP1 redisributable,
vb.net 3.5

plz help me.Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have a default printer for cards or something similar.
Change your printer and execute again.

Comment: As @Harval said, go to File -> Page Setup  and check no printer to remove any default printer you may have assigned to that report.